# FOR Loop container in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis

I am using the FOR LOOP container in SSIS 2012. I want this Loop to execute unless the value of a Boolean variable that I have is FALSE.
However when I try to set the EvalExpression property of the For Loop container I get an error:
Cannot convert 'System.Boolean' to 'System.String'.
I set the expression as:

```
@[User::myVar] = FALSE
```

How can I set the expression so that if the value is false then I break out of the FOR LOOP?

Comment: What is the data type for `@[User::myVar]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one to two issues.

The first is that myVar must be of type Boolean

The second and more insidious is that you are assigning a value `=` of False to your variable. What you want to do is *test* whether your variable is False. The comparison operator is `==`

[image]

Comment: it was of type Boolean, i needed to use ==.

Comment: I've also run into a huge pain trying to set EvalExpression to a variable because that's what I would intuitively expect it to accept. As it turns out, it looks like it will take the initial value and wont re-evaluate if you just place a value instead of an operation. 

Meaning, whatever @[User::myVar] was defaulted to, that's what the for loop indefinitely. I would assume it'll reevaluate it the is an operator in the EvalExpression - even if you try to use Expressions